# How do I properly re-render an updated shoppingcart/ checkout in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, e-commerce, cart, saleor

Im building an ecommerce, and am using Saleor as my headless backend. For my storefront, I initiated a project from a Next.js storefront [starter](https://github.com/saleor/nextjs-commerce) for saleor.

Now I have run into an issue, and since Im fairly new to React/ Next.js, and FE in general, I have a question regarding state management of the shopping cart.

The `Checkout`(cart) is stored on the server, and this is pre configured by saleor. In the storefront app, the `Checkout ID` is stored in a cookie, which is then fetched to render the cart. The method they used setting this up requires all the cart actions, i.e adding item, removing etc, to call `router.refresh();` in order for the cart to re-render the new updated state. IMO, this is not desired, as it makes CSS and etc reload, causing wierd flickering etc on the screen. I would like to have the cart state updated without having to do a page refresh. How can I accomplish this?

cart.tsx

```
import { getCart } from 'lib/saleor';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import CartModal from './modal';

export default async function Cart() {
  const cartId = cookies().get('cartId')?.value;
  let cart;

  if (cartId) {
    cart = await getCart(cartId);
  }

  return <CartModal cart={cart} />;
}
```

add-to-cart.tsx

```
'use client';

import { PlusIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { addItem } from 'components/cart/actions';
import LoadingDots from 'components/loading-dots';
import { ProductVariant } from 'lib/types';
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useTransition } from 'react';

export function AddToCart({
  variants,
  availableForSale,
}: {
  variants: ProductVariant[];
  availableForSale: boolean;
}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const defaultVariantId = variants.length === 1 ? variants[0]?.id : undefined;
  const variant = variants.find((variant: ProductVariant) =>
    variant.selectedOptions.every(
      (option) => option.value === searchParams.get(option.name.toLowerCase()),
    ),
  );
  const selectedVariantId = variant?.id || defaultVariantId;
  const title = !availableForSale
    ? 'Out of stock'
    : !selectedVariantId
    ? 'Please select options'
    : undefined;

  return (
    <button
      aria-label="Add item to cart"
      disabled={isPending || !availableForSale || !selectedVariantId}
      title={title}
      onClick={() => {
        // Safeguard in case someone messes with `disabled` in devtools.
        if (!availableForSale || !selectedVariantId) return;

        startTransition(async () => {
          const error = await addItem(selectedVariantId);

          if (error) {
            // Trigger the error boundary in the root error.js
            throw new Error(error.toString());
          }

          router.refresh();
        });
      }}
      className={clsx(
        'relative flex w-full items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-blue-600 p-4 tracking-wide text-white hover:opacity-90',
        {
          'cursor-not-allowed opacity-60 hover:opacity-60': !availableForSale || !selectedVariantId,
          'cursor-not-allowed': isPending,
        },
      )}
    >
      <div className="absolute left-0 ml-4">
        {!isPending ? <PlusIcon className="h-5" /> : <LoadingDots className="mb-3 bg-white" />}
      </div>
      <span>{availableForSale ? 'Add To Cart' : 'Out Of Stock'}</span>
    </button>
  );
}
```

I have tried some different solutions, but since I'm fairly unexperienced I would like some guidance and make sure i'm approaching this in the right way.